# Are there any halachic sources that discuss the Qumran calendar?

Tags: calendar

As a Torah reader, I was fascinated when I visited *Heichal Hasefer* - "Shrine of the Book" and read about the Qumran society and their calendar. As far as I know, there doesn't seem to be much, if anything, mentioned about them or their calendar in the Talmud. At least I'm not finding it via web searches.

Is there anything mentioned in the Talmud or other "halachic" sources (Midrash, etc.) about their calendar? If so, please provide references.

Comment: Is there anything at Qumran discussed in the Talmud?

Comment: Regarding your question about "their calendar", are you referring to the taking into account of both the Solar and Lunar cycles in regard to larger scale Torah cycles, as contrasted to only considering the Lunar cycle (like the Molad and Rosh Chodesh, etc.)?

Comment: @DoubleAA There are a whole variety of texts and text fragments from Qumran. Some of those texts are mentioned in Talmud in various places and under a whole range of subjects. But it sound likes what you are trying to bring out by your comment is that the Qumran community itself is not (to my knowledge) the subject of discussion in Talmud. Would that be accurate?

Comment: @YaacovDeane Ideally, I'm looking to compare their calendar with the current Judaic calendar. My understanding is that the Qumran calendar was strictly solar, with probable intercalation. I'm curious if either Bavli or Yerushalmi has any discussion about their calendar in any way.

Comment: There are discussions of the subject in the context of Birchat HaChamah. The concept also relates to Yovelot cycles and the creation of the universe but that second subject is more in the context of Kabbalistic concepts.

Comment: In Vermes' Dead Sea Scrolls In English there's a whole bunch of calendar-type text fragments grouped together, along with a little bit of discussion of it--the 30 day months with an extra day every 3 months.  No leap years for the extra quarter day, things must have shifted a bit over the life of the Yachad.  There also was a calendar as the first part of the Letter to King Yonatan, which implies that they were trying to get their calendar used by the entire State.

Comment: Here's an article on the calendar - https://www.academia.edu/523554/The_364-day_Year_in_the_Dead_Sea_Scrolls_and_Jewish_Pseudepigrapha  not much in the way of Talmud references, but it does reference its use in Enoch and Jubilees